# How to get sound portion of an MP4 (video file)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, mp4, aac

I am developing a windows phone 7 application and it does video recording. I would like to get the sound portion of the video file (MP4) and do some enhancements on the sound. I believe sound is saved as AAC frames in MP4. (Right?) How can I extract sound of a videa MP4 file?

Since this is a video file, it can be huge file. So uploading to cloud and processing there is not a good option. Since this WP7 application I cannot use unmaged dlls :( Is there a way to do in pure C#? Any open source tools/samples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

MP4 is a container format and realistically the sound portion isn't always AAC. It could be MP3 or any other number of different audio formats. You may be thinking of M4A, which I believe requires either AAC or ALAC.

On the subject of audio extraction, it should be possible to extract the audio from an MP4 using just managed code. You'll have to read up on the MP4 format ([here](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000155.shtml), for example - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057157/anyone-familiar-with-mp4-data-structure) is also worth reading) and then search through the file for the location of the audio and then either copy it to its own buffer or do your manipulations in chunks. Even then, you'll have to be able to recognize when it isn't an audio format that your app won't support.

It's possible that there already exists a .net library that can do all of this but I don't know of any. It's probably not very popular because managed code is definitely not the best angle to approach this from, but considering this is Windows Phone, it is, as you noted, your only avenue of approach.

Good luck!