# Transcode/Convert Video to Mp4 on Android

Tags: android, video

I've a requirement where I need to transcode small video clips shot from Native camera app to lower bitrate/resolution Mp4 which is shreable via email etc.

What is the best way to transcode/convert the video on device itself. FFMPEG or any other library?

p.s. I know this is an overkill for the device but client leaves me with no option. He doesn't care about battery or time it takes. I'm targeting this for quad-cores, where CPU is not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use something like ffmpeg which has been ported to Android (see this SO post: [ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk) and the ffmpeg port for android which is here: http://bambuser.com/opensource).  You'll have to use JNI etc, but that will save you the hassle of dealing with the byte stream yourself.

Comment: I've seen this one. I want a ready made solution, I don't want to invest time building and resolving c code issues and then write JNI. I'm sure someone might have already done it.

Comment: @geeknizer IF you want a "ready made solution" you should be asking on a usage forum such as android.stackexchange rather than on stack overflow.

Comment: well, I've raised another question for the problem I'm facing with Bambuser binary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586816/transcoding-mp4-video-on-android-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it on Android myself, so YMMV:

[Is there a Java API for mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015393/is-there-a-java-api-for-mp4-files)

http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/

Answer (score -1):

If you're recording on-device, why not set the expected format from your code? It appears the api lets you set video size, framerate etc. in the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) class.

Comment: yes but Continuos auto-focus doesn't work. Also if you shoot at lower resolution, you dont get 30fps.