# Is it possible to convert 3gp to mp4

Tags: android

In my app I have to record video in `.mp4` format, but by default camera is recording in `.3gp` format. So far, I have only been able to change the file extension to `.mp4` format, but video is recorded in `.3gp` only. How can I record video in `.mp4` format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transcode/Convert Video to Mp4 on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346031/transcode-convert-video-to-mp4-on-android)