# Looking for pure Java API to read metadata from an MP4 file

Tags: java, mp4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Java API for mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015393/is-there-a-java-api-for-mp4-files)

I am looking for a pure Java api that can read MP4 metadata.  I have been trying to look online for one but have not found anything
suitable. If there are no good api's, can someone point me to resources on how to parse metadata from an MP4, tutorials would be great
as well. I have looked online for that as well but have not found much. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see that the question was closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate question is about a general api for mp4 files. If you just want to read the meta-data, try Apache Tika - http://tika.apache.org

Comment: Apache Tika is now using https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/ and you might use it directly